# How do you add event to Trac event time line

Tags: python, plugins, trac

I am writing a plug-in for Trac. I would like to add an event to the time line each time the plug-in receives some data from a Git post-receive hook.

Looking at [the timeline API](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/timeline/api.py), it seems you can only add new source of events. So you are responsible for retrieving and displaying the data. I would prefer saving my event to an existent source.

Where should I look in the Trac API to save events?

ps: my plan is to rely on a remote repository and remote web interface to the code like Github.

pss: The time line has to display commits from the main project git repository and its clones. I don't want to host a copy of every repository that matter to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeline API is a level higher than what you need to do. There is a general VCS implementation of it in [ChangesetModule](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/versioncontrol/web_ui/changeset.py), which delegates the changeset (event) retrieval itself to a VCS-specific `Repository`. So you should implement [the versioncontrol API](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/versioncontrol/api.py) instead.

The API is designed for a “pull model”, in which Trac queries the VCS when constructing a timeline. If you really prefer a “push model” (why?), you could try working off [the CacheRepository implementation](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/versioncontrol/cache.py) as a base, injecting your events into the cache, or just writing an event-storing repository from scratch. Be aware that this goes against the grain of the existing design, and will very probably be unnecessary extra effort.

I suggest that you go with the normal pull model instead, it will be easier and cleaner. You could use [the Subversion implementation](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/trac/versioncontrol/svn_fs.py) or [the Mercurial implementation](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/sandbox/mercurial-plugin/tracvc/hg/backend.py) as a reference, and probably use [GitPython](http://gitorious.org/projects/git-python/) to talk to `git`.

Comment: I am going for a push model before I want use to track activity on a project and of all its clone.